# How to get a specific key from jsonb in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have column in jsonb named "lines" with many object like this :

```json
[
 {
  "a" : "1", 
  "b" : "2", 
  "c" : "3"
 }, 
 {
  "a" : "4", 
  "b" : "5", 
  "c" : "6"
 }
]
```

This is my query

```sql
SELECT *
FROM public.test
WHERE public.test.lines::jsonb ? '[{"c"}]'
```

In my query i want to get only rows which contain the "c" key in this array
But i have nothing after execution

Comment: The column `test.lines` should be declared with the type `jsonb` so that you don't need to cast it every time you want to do something useful with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `?` operator only works with strings, not with json objects. If you want to test if any of the array elements contains a key with the value `c` you can use a JSON path predicate:

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE lines::jsonb @@ '$[*].c != null'
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution:

```
SELECT
    'c',
    *
FROM
    jsonb_path_query('[{"a": "1", "b": "2", "c": "3"}, {"a": "4", "b": "5", "c": "6"}]', '$[*].c');

 ?column? | jsonb_path_query 
----------+------------------
 c        | "3"
 c        | "6"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response Adrian but it doesn’t do exactly what I want

Comment: Since you have not provided an example of exactly what you want that is not surprising. Add expected output as update to your question.

Comment: Yes sorry for that

Comment: You still have not shown what you want the output to be.